# Metric on $V \otimes V$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, metric-spaces

Given an hermitian metric on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb C $, is there a "standard" way to put a metric on $V \otimes V$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Define $\langle a\otimes b,c\otimes d\rangle = \langle a,c \rangle \cdot \langle b,d\rangle$ and extend using bilinearity.  This has the nice property that if $e_1, \ldots e_m$ is an orthonormal basis for $V_1$ and $f_1,\ldots f_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $f_2$, then $e_i\otimes f_j$ is an orthonormal basis for $V_1\otimes V_2$.

Comment: Note that this corresponds exactly to the metric $g \otimes g$, if we consider metrics on $V$ to be equivalent to symmetric isomorphisms $g : V \to V^*$. Point being that the definition isn't pulled out of a hat; it comes directly from the tensor product.